# foundation orbit not working after I added other jquery

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, orbit

I'm working with Foundation to build a site, part of the site was a Foundation orbit slideshow, which was working perfectly until I added a jquery code for an image swap. The image swap is on the social buttons on the bottom of the page and that is working correctly.  I've searched around and found similar topics, I tried to work through their solutions but could only get the opposite to occur (orbit started working, image swap stopped working).   [The site can be viewed here](http://www.sals-pals.com/dev/salspals/new/rates.html)

Comment: Looks like you have lost control of your $

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, how do I regain control?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go.
jQuery:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".img-swap").hover(
        function(){
            this.src = (this.src == "img/facebook.png")?"img/facebookgrey.png":this.src;
            this.src = (this.src == "img/yelp.png")?"img/yelpgrey.png":this.src;
            this.src = (this.src == "img/googleplus.png")?"img/googleplusgrey.png":this.src;
        },
        function(){
            this.src = (this.src == "img/facebookgrey.png")?"img/facebook.png":this.src;
            this.src = (this.src == "img/yelpgrey.png")?"img/yelp.png":this.src;
            this.src = (this.src == "img/googleplusgrey.png")?"img/googleplus.png":this.src;
    });
});
```

Comment: I switched that in and the orbit is still doing the same as before, and the rollovers have stopped working :(, I uploaded it so the original link is with your updated code